# Convert Pinescript V2 to V5

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling to find the way to convert below V2 pinescript to V5

```
//@version=2
strategy(title="abc", shorttitle="abc", overlay = true)
AdvSymbolVolume = input(title="A+", type=symbol, defval="NSE:RELIANCE")
DecSymbolVolume = input(title="D-", type=symbol, defval="NSE:RELIANCE")
Resolutin = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="D")
BuyBand = input(40, maxval =100)
SellBand = input(-40, minval=-100)
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
xASVValue = security(AdvSymbolVolume, Resolutin, open)
xDSVValue = security(DecSymbolVolume, Resolutin, open)
xADV = xASVValue - xDSVValue
nRes = (xADV - nz(xADV[1], 0)) * 100 / (xASVValue + xDSVValue)
pos = iff(nRes > BuyBand, 1,
         iff(nRes < SellBand, -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
possig = iff(reverse and pos == 1, -1,
          iff(reverse and pos == -1, 1, pos))      
if (possig == 1) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (possig == -1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

I am stuck with the variable type of **pos** and how nz(pos[1], 0)  is being calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nz()` replaces the NaN values with the given value. In your case, if the value of `pos` on the previous bar is NaN, it will replace it with `0`.

Having said that, there are two changes you should be aware of when going from v2 to v3.

[Self-referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed). So, you should first define `pos` and the re-assign a value to it:

```
pos = 0
pos := iff(nRes > BuyBand, 1,
         iff(nRes < SellBand, -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
```

The second change you should know about is [Default behaviour of security function has changed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed).

So, in order to achieve the same results, you should add `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` to your `security()` call which is not really recommended because you will be accessing future data. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead) to understand that parameter better.